# Lifecycle when phone is turned off?

Tags: android

I have a problem. I made a multiplayer game entirely based on Firebase realtime database. It's game of words. Users can connect to each other, joining a specific room etc.

I have set all my lifecycle's toward firebase correctly. What I mean is, if user goes `onStop();` he goes .`removeValue("online");` in firebase and thus being removed from a game lobby.
However I have problem when I exit from Emulator , my `onDestroy()` is not called, and user still appears online in a game which is causing a mayor problem for a game.
Would any of this cause problem if phone power is off?

Giving the circumstances I am only familiar with android development, how do I solve this problem?